# Quickblox android MediaStreamManager null on x86 devices

Tags: java, android, quickblox, quickblox-android

Why localVideoTrack black screen on asus devices ? or maybe x86 devices..

here my session output

No Problem :

```
`QBRTCSession{
sessionDescription=QBRTCSessionDescription{
sessionID='49ad7725-d51e-47ba-a893-de4ec6e4f227’, 
callerID='23516178’, 
opponents=[24464093], 
conferenceType=QBConferenceType{value='1'}, 
userInfo={opp_avatar=hidden_link, from=Alice Renadewa, id=dummy, avatar=hidden_link}}, 
MediaStreamManager=com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBMediaStreamManager@fa98cef, 
channels={24464093=com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBPeerConnection@7682e34}, 
signalChannel=com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBSignalChannel@3fc03fc, 
eventsCallbacks=[com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCClient$SessionClosedListener@c6caa85, 
com.cendana2000.realcom.modules.login.LoginActivity@d624914, 
com.cendana2000.realcom.modules.videoCall.VideoCallActivity@ab8f7f8], 
state=QB_RTC_SESSION_CONNECTING}`
```

Problem :

```
`QBRTCSession{
sessionDescription=QBRTCSessionDescription{
sessionID='7dcb5b34-61c4-42b4-a7db-dea0a3fb656d’, 
callerID='23516178’, 
opponents=[24464093], 
conferenceType=QBConferenceType{value='1'}, 
userInfo={opp_avatar=hidden_link, avatar=hidden_link, id=dummy, from=Alice Renadewa}}, 
MediaStreamManager=null, 
channels={24464093=com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBPeerConnection@22610278}, 
signalChannel=com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBSignalChannel@21de6ba8, 
eventsCallbacks=[com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCClient$SessionClosedListener@21dcc8b0, 
com.cendana2000.realcom.modules.videoCall.VideoCallActivity@2245bf40], 
state=QB_RTC_SESSION_CONNECTING}`
```